# Validate XML against XSD generated class

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, xsd, xml-serialization

Is it possible to validate XML against a Serializable class rather than and XSD?

I would rather do this as my business layer has a reference to the class whereas if I was to validate the XSD I would have to Create a XmlSchemaSet and pass a reference through.

If not what is the best solution for validating the XML bearing in mind performance is an issue as this will happen every call on the service I am writing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to deserialize the xml as the class you are expecting it represents. If it works without exception it is valid.

Comment: And if it's not it throws an exception.  Is that the only solution to get a list of parsing errors?  It seems a bit crude

Comment: yes it is actually crude, but no other ideas. May be the best is checking against the xsd.

Comment: On reflection maybe I can use the CanDeSerialize method and if not then I can fall over to using XmlSchemaValidator or something to get parsing errors?

Comment: @Sheff validating against the XSD is surely the best way togo.

Comment: Yes but there are 2 big (but separate) issues. 1) It is a big performance hit when 95% of calls are likely to be valid and 2) It requires a Schemaset creating and passing to the Business layer when really the schema is already defined by the class.

Comment: @Sheff I've solution in production using the XSD validation strategy. The performance does not impact so much, and the benefit of error checking is great. Passing the xsd is not an issue in my case since is deployied with the solution and it stays as a file in the server.

Comment: That sounds promising then. Do you just use an xmlReader with a validate event handler?

Comment: In the end I did the above but then if it could not deserialize then I used an XMLReader to validate to get any validation errors